# How to load multiple .mat files into a python script

Tags: python, scipy

I want to load 38 .mat files into a dictionary to hold them all. 
the .mat files are named subject1 to subject38
The code I tried is a simple for loop

```
    import scipy.io as sio
    data = {}
    for i in range(1, 38):
        data["data{}".format(i)] = sio.loadmat('subject{}.mat'.format(i))
```

the error I'm getting is:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/senior project/python/dataAqu.py", line 7, in 
    data["data{0}".format(i)] = sio.loadmat('subject{0}.mat'.format(i))
  File "C:\Users\mamdo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 208, in loadmat
    matfile_dict = MR.get_variables(variable_names)
  File "C:\Users\mamdo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 292, in get_variables
    res = self.read_var_array(hdr, process)
  File "C:\Users\mamdo\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio5.py", line 252, in read_var_array
    return self._matrix_reader.array_from_header(header, process)
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 675, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 705, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.array_from_header
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 778, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_real_complex
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 450, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_numeric
  File "mio5_utils.pyx", line 355, in scipy.io.matlab.mio5_utils.VarReader5.read_element
  File "streams.pyx", line 194, in scipy.io.matlab.streams.ZlibInputStream.read_string
  File "pyalloc.pxd", line 9, in scipy.io.matlab.pyalloc.pyalloc_v
MemoryError

Comment: A comment on the loop: to load the matrices with suffix 1...38, the loop should be `for i in range(1,39):`. Regarding the error message: how big are the `.mat` files?

Comment: Each .mat file is approximately 250 MB. I restarted my pc and this error stopped occuring but now because of the file size the python script runs into a memory problem.

Comment: Why must you load them all at the same time? Can you loop through them one at a time?

Comment: I changed the code to load the mat file inside the loop so the mat files are not loaded all at once and it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the problem. The mat files shouldnt be opened by any other program - like matlab - if there is an error restart the computer.

Also if there is a memory problem try to integrate the mat files seperatly and perform whatever code you need and then load the next file.